# Matching Facebook userID to FirebaseId

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

Currently I am using facbook as my provider to log in to firebase.
The uid I get from that I save.

Next I make a call to the Facebook Graph api to retrieve a list of friends who use the current app.
I also get an id with this call but they do not match with the uid I get at login.

I would need a way to map my firebase users logged in with facebook to the friend list I get from the graph api.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: the uid is generated by Firebase. They have to generate this id because they support different login providers. What kind of id do you get back from Facebook? Did you have a look at the Firebase Admin Interface where you can see all your registered users?

Comment: Hey Micheal, Thanks for the reply.
I found the problem was just being stupid.
The id's were right I was just checking the wrong ids

Comment: @BobDeKort how did you find the firebase id from a facebook users facebook id.  Could you post your answer?